# Writing data from excel to .txt with transpose using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to import data stored within INPUT_01.xlsx with the aim of writing the data into an .txt with correct CRLF tags. I'm facing an issue where the IDE terminal shows the output I need in a loop but when the data is written into the .txt it only writes the final row I have in my excel. I need the python code to print all rows (it should figure that out by max_rows output) with the formatting into the .txt and close the .txt file.

```
import openpyxl
path = "c:/python/inputs/INPUT_01.xlsx"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
m_row = sheet_obj.max_row

for i in range(1, m_row + 1):
    cell_obj0 = sheet_obj.cell(row=i, column=1)
    cell_obj1 = sheet_obj.cell(row=i, column=2)
    cell_obj3 = sheet_obj.cell(row=i, column=3)
    text=(cell_obj0.value+'\n'+cell_obj1.value+'\n'+cell_obj0.value+'\n')
    print(text)
    print(text,file=open('c:/python/Outputs/filename4.txt','w'))
```

[INPUT_01.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIr4C.png)
[filename4.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6BXo.png)

[IDE image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol0jF.png)

I have gotten so far getting the expected output in the correct format although I cannot get the loop to occur properly for all of the active rows in the workbook active sheet. I'm missing a small trick as I have a very specific requirement to select specific columns (without header) and its values to be transposed. I.e. write the data of each row, across defined columns within the workbook transposed in a .txt. Once a row is finished it should write the next row in the similar fashion until the end of active rows.

Comment: Try changing the mode when trying to open the file from "w" to "a"

Comment: You should probably open the output file once not in your for loop.  As written, you will overwrite the file for each iteration, thus just see the last entry.

Comment: Dear @ShehrozChishty, itprorh66 Thank you and it worked. Any suggestions to save each row into of the excel into one .txt document with a file mask i.e. ISO_inbound_YYYYMMDD_hh:mm:ss.txt?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
import openpyxl
import datetime
import time

path = "my_excel_file.xlsx"

# Load the Excel file
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

# Select the worksheet
worksheet = workbook.active

# Loop through each row in the worksheet, min_row=2 means ignore column headings
for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    # Get the values in the row
    values = [str(cell) for cell in row]

    # Gets the current timestamp
    current_timestamp = time.time()

    # Converts the timestamp to a datetime object
    current_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current_timestamp)

    # Formats timestamp to string
    current_time_str = current_time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

    # Create a filename for the text file
    filename = f"ISO_inbound_{current_time_str}.txt"
    
    # Open the file for writing
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        # Write the values to the file, separated by tabs
        file.write('\t'.join(values))

    # One sec delay to avoid file overwrite
    time.sleep(1)
```